# How to use PHPUnit in Behat when using Symfony's PHPUnit Bridge?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, behat

In my Behat context, I've been included PHPUnit's assertions as described in [the manual](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html#more-about-steps):

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';
```

However, I'm now using Symfony's [PHPUnit bridge](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html) and so I've removed my explicitly-installed PHPUnit and am using the one brought in by the bridge.  I needed to do this to avoid the "multiple versions" error described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2174).

But now, I can't use PHPUnit in behat!

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'
```

How can I reference the PHPUnit instance brought in by the PHPUnit bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to require the relevant files in vendor by their path instead.  For me, that was:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7/src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php');
```

Comment: @lauda you can't accept your own answers to questions for 2 days, I'm afraid.  But I plan to.

Comment: You might want to report this upstream as well. As this is Behat related it might see some traction (or has a better solution already).

Comment: Interesting idea, @hakre.  I'm not quite sure where I'd report this, though.

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 4, this was enough to get it working for me:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7/vendor/autoload.php');
```

However it's not a great solution ongoing, as PHPUnit Bridge will install PHPUnit 6.3 instead of 5.7 if you're using PHP 7.2.

I tried changing composer.json as follows:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "vendor/bin/.phpunit"
    ]
},
```

which does work, but breaks a fresh install because the folder doesn't exist until you run `simple-phpunit`.

I suspect this could be worked around using composer scripts to run `simple-phpunit`, but my brief experiments with `post-install-cmd` and `pre-autoload-dump` got me nowhere.